# Python - remove commas and leave decimal points from string as number

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, regex

As of title, I need to remove commas from string number and leave decimal point, but the problem is input can be with `.` or `,`. This input will be saved for Django model's `DecimalField`

For example:

###### Input:

"250,000,50"
"250,000"
"250000.00"
"25,000"

###### Output:

250000.50
250000.00
250000.00
25000.00

##### What I have tried:

```
def _normalize_amount(self, value -> str):
   normalized_amount = value[:-3].replace(",", "") + value[-3:]
   return Decimal(normalized_amount)
```

Problem is that this function can not handle the cases where user enters `,` as decimal point. How to solve this case ?

Comment: How is `250,000,001234` supposed to be parsed? Or `250,000.12345`?

Comment: That case likely won't happen, so it does not matter. @gog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search if the number has one or two digits after last decimal point, e.g.:

```py
import re

text = """\
250,000,50
250,000
250000.00
25,000"""

pat = r"([\d,.]+?)([,.]\d{,2})?$"

for a1, a2 in re.findall(pat, text, flags=re.M):
    print("".join(re.findall(r"\d+", a1)) + f".{a2[1:].zfill(2)}")
```

Prints:

```
250000.50
250000.00
250000.00
25000.00
```